# Value for checkbox is not true when checked in MVC 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a very strange case, where I post a value from a checkbox to my controller, it's not true, even when checked!

Part of my viewModel:

```
public class BeslutIStortViewDTO
{
    public BeslutIStortDTO BeslutIStort { get; set; }
    public BeslutIStortListorDTO SelectListor { get; set; }
}

public class BeslutIStortDTO
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public bool Ok { get; set; }
    ... other stuff
}
```

part of my view:

```
<div id="colOk" class="kolumn_header">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BeslutIStort.Ok)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.BeslutIStort.Ok, new { @class = "rensa", tabindex = 5 })
</div>
```

In the string passed to the controller, when the box in unchecked, everything seems ok:

```
BeslutIStort.Ok=false
```

BUT! When I check it:

```
BeslutIStort.Ok=&BeslutIStort.Ok=false
```

Its twice in the string, the first has no value, the oterh is `false`, so both are wrong. I would of course expect only one, and that one to be `true`.

Another interesting finding is that in the acutal rendered html, the checkbox looks like this:

```
<input class="rensa" id="BeslutIStort_Ok" name="BeslutIStort.Ok" tabindex="5" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="BeslutIStort.Ok" type="hidden" value="false" />
```

It has a hidden field!

When I post to the values to the server, I do it with ajax, and the data parameter is defined like this:

```
data: $("#BisData").serialize(),
```

I hope someone could help me to shed some light into this, and help me getting some "true" to my controller :-)

=== S O L V E D ===
As it tured out, I had javascript like this:

$(".rensa").val("");

Which made the checkbox non functional. I added this:

$(".rensaCheckbox").attr("checked", false);

for the checkboxes, so now it works.

Comment: #BisData is form tag id?

Comment: k.. u add alert($("#BisData").serialize()); put this output here...

Comment: It's the two rows of code I've got in the question, BeslutIStort.Ok=&BeslutIStort.Ok=false and BeslutIStort.Ok=false. It also contains other data, but that is normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it aint that strange either.. 
first of all you have recieved the value two times `BeslutIStort.Ok=&BeslutIStort.Ok=false`
because Razor engine automatically puts a hidden field with the same name  and value false inside the form when ever you use `@Html.CheckboxFor()`
this is done so that even if the checkbox isnt checked a `false` value is returned.

second... you are recieveing null value because there is no value on your input(checkbox) html control. if you want that a value should be returned just add one with the following code

```
<div id="colOk" class="kolumn_header">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BeslutIStort.Ok)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.BeslutIStort.Ok, new { @class = "rensa", tabindex = 5,value="true" })
</div>
```

Comment: It changes the generated html, to <input class="rensa" id="BeslutIStort_Ok" name="BeslutIStort.Ok" tabindex="5" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="BeslutIStort.Ok" type="hidden" value="false" /> , but it's unfortunately the same when serializing it.

Comment: u mean you are something like this...BeslutIStort.Ok=&BeslutIStort.Ok=false

Comment: Yes, when checked. When not check, it's BeslutIStort.Ok=false only

Comment: i mean when its checked now arnt u getting BeslutIStort.Ok=true&BeslutIStort.Ok=false

Comment: No, I was expecting that, it's still BeslutIStort.Ok=&BeslutIStort.Ok=false  (one empty and one false)

Comment: The problem was acutally in some other javascript. See the edit in my original question. I marked your answer as acceptet, as it was correct with the given information, and useful as it got me in the right direction towards solving the problem